# Fault Tolerance in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

We know in hadoop if data corrupts a new replica will be created suddenly if node which was down initally works fine then how will namenode deals with 4 replicas will it delete one node?

If so the newly created one or the one which was up suddenly?

Comment: The old node meta data will removed from the Namenode, so even If the corrupted node come back up, name node will have no Meta data about the data stored in it. Hence Hadoop will have 3 replicas (2 old and one new replica created after one of the old one got corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

In the situation when one `data node` goes down, `name node` will see some data blocks `under-replicated` and will start replication to other node in the cluster to bring the replication back to the expected level (default 3).

When the corrupted node goes up again all blocks from this node will be seen by as `over-replicated` with 4 replicas.

When a block becomes `over-replicated`, the `name node` chooses a replica to remove. The `name node` will prefer not to reduce the number of racks that host replicas, and secondly prefer to remove a replica from the `data node` with the least amount of available disk space. This may help rebalancing the load over the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

NameNode takes care of over-replication blocks, and you don't have to worry about over-replicated blocks or do anything manually.

Namenode deletes over-replicated blocks from the node which has less available disk space .. which eventually helps in cluster re-balancing.